# In IE 8 to show an Image, image/abc.gif and image\abc.gif both are working fine but in IE 11 it isn't. Can somebody help me out with this why

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

I was working with some issue where image was not getting loaded on user computer by using IE11.
I had no issue seeing this because I was using IE8. 
By some research I found out this issue. I am not getting any error o  my computer with IE8. 
"image/img1.gif"
"image\img2.gif"
I was using above example for two image and both were working in IE8 but not in IE11.

Thanks

Comment: We have no clue.... Where is the code that is not working?

Comment: Can't share the code due to security policy, but yes in inspect element I found out this. and by editing there live I encountered this issue.

Comment: Create [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have found the answer of this issue. It was because of the new update of Microsoft, 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4491113/cumulative-update-for-internet-explorer-february-19-2019

After updating this I am able to use both / and \ in image src path in the HTML page. 
Thanks Guys.

Comment: I suggest that you coud mark your solution as answer if it solved your problem.And this will be helpful to someone meets with the same problem.